# Moving wordpress from directory to root

Tags: wordpress

I have my wordpress in a folder, i updated the url options in the wordpress genereal settings to the root folder, i then copied all the files from the directory to the root.

I have not deleted the old directory yet!

When i go to log in, i can not do so, in the url it still says redirect to the old directoy.

What should i do, do i have to delete the ole directory?

Answer (score -1):

See [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) for the process of moving to root and [Changing The Site URL « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for admin recovery instructions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: True, but #1: it's a 5 year old answer, and #2) if you looked at the links, you'd see that the instructions are far too complex to dump into an answer here.